# Multiplying complex signal with its own complex conjugate transposed copy?

Tags: matlab, audio, frequency-spectrum, signal-power, signal-energy

Let input be a real (audio) signal, and let `X` be its complex frequency domain representation.

What does the output represent when the frequency domain signal is multiplied with its own [complex conjugate transposed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) copy? What does this product phisicaly represent?

`X' * X`

Comment: It corresponds to the spectrum of autocorrelation (see the bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Efficient_computation).

Comment: That sounds like homework ?

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe notation $X'$ for the conjugate transpose is used in Matlab, and is a bit ambiguous. More common notations for what is also called the [Hermitian transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) are $X^H$ or $X^*$.

Dimensions are important.

- This would be a sloppy writing, yet
  if the product were pointwise, $X \cdot X' \to X[n] \cdot \overline{X[n]}$ would simply be the power spectrum  $X \cdot X' =|X|^2$ ([answer by Alfredo Solari](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78776/15892)).
- Suppose that $X\in \mathbb{C^{1\times N}}$, then the result is a scalar, this is actually the dot product:  $$X \cdot X' = \sum_{n\in N} X[n] \overline{X[n]}\,.$$
  This would be the energy of the spectrum. And therefore that of the signal (up to a factor), if the  "complex frequency domain representation" is energy preserving (like a Fourier transform).
- Suppose that $X\in \mathbb{C^{N\times 1}}$, then the result is a matrix, whose diagonal is the power spectrum ([answer by Hilmar](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78779/15892)).

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying a complex number by it's conjugate, gives you the square of the modulus of said complex number.

The modulus of the complex Fourier is the power spectrum of the signal.

So multiplying your frequency domain representation by it's conjugate will give you the square of the power spectrum of that signal. This power spectrum links to reality and physics in that is proportional to the power of the acoustic signal that the mic sampled.

The constant of proportionality will depend on your sampling frequency.

This is also valid if you are using a time-frequency domain technique like Short Time Fourier Transform or Wavelet Transform.

Comment: Please note it's not just conjugate, it's conjugate transposed matrix.

Comment: Oohh, so sorry, so matrix multiplication, no "point-to-point" multiplication ?

Answer (score 0):

The result is a square matrix or a scalar depending on whether the signal is a row or a column vector.

The diagonal of this matrix is the power spectrum (which is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation). I'm not sure the other elements of this matrix have any physical relevance.

The scalar is the sum of the power spectrum which is proportional to the total energy. If you use $1/\sqrt{N}$ scaling for the FFT it is the total energy (per Perseval's theorem), i.e. it equals $\sum x^2(n)$

Comment: Hilmar, the result is a scalar.

Comment: Good point. That of course depends if you start with a row or column vector. If it's scalar, than it's the total energy or something proportional to it (depending on the scaling conventions of the FFT being used).